# Python : Directory bottom level cap

Tags: python

Here is my code that walks through directories and deletes all found jpg images.

What i would like to do is to set the bottom level cap for directories. (Include folders before level, exclude folders after level).

It works well when i want to set the top level cap (skips first two levels): `islice(2,2,None)`, but does not work for bottom cap (for example level 2): `islice(0,2,None)`. It kinda includes all the following directories no matter the stop is set.

```
import os 
from itertools import islice

def drop_n_elements(start,stop,iterable):
    next(islice(iterable, start, stop, None))

dir = r'test'

iterable = os.walk(dir)
drop_n_elements(0, 2, iterable)

for root, dirs, files in iterable:
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith(("jpg")):
            os.remove(os.path.join(root, name))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just doing `next` in your function, so it moves to the next position of `iterable` but does not return the `islice`. That's why it works for the first case but not the second. You need to do this in the function:

```
def drop_n_elements(start, stop, iterable):
    return itertools.islice(iterable, start, stop)
```

And then, instead of just calling the function, assign its result:

```
iterable = drop_n_elements(0, 2, iterable)
```

You also don't need `None` in the `islice`, because the `step` is optional, but that wasn't causing any problems.